# Save image to a download folder on Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a web browser so I want to save an image and I'm using the following code.

```
private EditText editText;
private WebView webView;

private Button button3;

DownloadManager downloadManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);


    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);



    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (button3.isClickable()) {

                String a = webView.getUrl();


                downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(a);
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                Long reference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);



            }}


                });
```

well I can download the image when I press the button3, and yes I can save it the image but in this route /data/data/com.android.providers.downloads/cache/..

So I can't see the image on the gallery, I hope that someone can help me to save the image to another folder for example Download per default.

I got this errors on logcat

```
07-12 01:14:57.543 1305-1305/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1305: eglCreateSyncKHR(1641): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)

07-12 01:14:52.081 7102-7102/com.example.th.pp W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
07-12 01:14:52.097 7102-7102/com.example.th.pp W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 7102
07-12 01:14:52.431 7102-7102/com.example.th.pp W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
07-12 01:14:56.982 2167-2179/android.process.media W/DownloadManager: Path appears to be invalid: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/file.png
07-12 01:14:56.985 2167-2179/android.process.media E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
    java.lang.SecurityException: No permission to write to /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/file.png: Neither user 10076 nor current process has android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
        at android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:1613)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextImpl.java:1645)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextWrapper.java:707)
        at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider.checkFileUriDestination(DownloadProvider.java:756)
        at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider.insert(DownloadProvider.java:573)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:264)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:163)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
07-12 01:14:56.988 7102-7102/com.example.th.pp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-12 01:14:56.988 7102-7102/com.example.th.pp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.th.pp, PID: 7102
    java.lang.SecurityException: No permission to write to /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/file.png: Neither user 10076 nor current process has android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:476)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1274)
        at android.app.DownloadManager.enqueue(DownloadManager.java:1014)
        at com.example.think.pp.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:102)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it visible in your gallery, you need to save it to a more public location. Before you enqueue the request, add:

```
String fileName = "local.png";

request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir( //
    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, fileName );
```

This will also require you to add the following permission in your manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks when I write your code before enqueue and I try to download and image but the app get stopped, I'm new on android and here too and im learning english so my english it's not good at all, as soon as I wrote the answer I watched that a guy mark my errors about english and quit me  some points xd

Comment: When the app stops, it will produce an error message in [LogCat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html). Post that stack trace in your question.

Comment: Thanks, I added to my question the errors that was in red, I will hope your answer

Comment: I'm looking that the errors it's only produced at emulator I installed on my phone and the error is not present there

Comment: I edited my post, try adding that permission in your manifest.

Comment: Many many thanks man, your code has no errors on phones only on my emulator. I hope to learn soon cuz im too bad.